# Error al completar recaptcha

Tags: javascript, api, formularios, cuenta-usuario, recaptcha

estoy teniendo este problema muy seguido, cuando intento ingresar algun sitio que contiene captcha, generalmente arroja el error **"Error: Los parámetros de la API no son válidos. Prueba a volver a cargar la página."**
Espero puedan ayudarme
Gracias

[image: imagen del error]

Comment: ¿Has probado con otro navegador? ¿Has probado en buscar por internet ayuda? No se si esto entra en StackOverflow

Comment: Ya probe de todo, firefox, edge, opera, no encuentro nada q lo resuelva

Comment: ya encontraste solución al error??-- Me sucede lo mismo.

Comment: ¿Has probado con una pestaña del navegador en modo incógnito a ver ?

Comment: Hola, podrías comprobar esta serie de pasos descritos en esta página de soporte oficial de Google https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=es-419

Comment: Resuelto cambiando la clave.
Gracias

Answer (score 3):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings

"ProxySettingsPerUse" o "Predeterminado" cambia el valor a "1"

Comment: Sería bueno coloques la fuente que indicas te sirvió para resolver la duda

Answer (score 1):

Tuve que reinstalar el sistema operativo, esa fue la unica solucion, despues de probar todo.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Todo un SO por un CAPTCHA? 